# Just a quick one

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I peered through my microscope and was astonished to see a tiny tavern filled with boisterous organelles slapping each others' backs and spitting on the floor. That got me to thinking:

> What directionality is implied whilst rough outgoing nuclei gather?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer

> Is either right-to-left or west

Because:

> If you read the sentence from left-to-right, the first letters of the last five words spell "wrong"

However,

> If you read from right-to-left, the last letters of the (now first) five words spell "right" (credit to @Gareth McCaughan)

Which leads me to believe that

> The correct answer is found by flipping the sentence and reading from right to left

Therefore,

> I concluded that the correct answer is likely to be **any of** right-to-left (because we had to read the sentence from right to left), counter-clockwise (because nuclear spin is rotational), or west (because that's the direction you go if you go from right-to-left on a typical. The author of the question has since clarified that as they are organelles, they don't have nuclear spin, and either right-to-left or west is acceptable

Comment: Interestingly, if you look at the other ends in reverse, you get the opposite.

Comment: which suggests that the required answer might be the direction you go in to get that opposite result.

Comment: (Moose, the basic idea here is yours and if you think that's likely to be the intended answer then I suggest that you edit your answer to say so.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice (and great find)! I've adjusted my answer

Comment: For what it's worth, I was just looking for right to left, the direction that gives you the "right" answer. These are organelles, or cell nuclei, which don't have spin. The map direction is also acceptable as an answer. Well done!

Comment: Ah, I didn't really read much of the prologue; that makes it a little clearer